# Javafx. Controller Initialize method and spring @PostConstruct cannot use together

Tags: java, spring, javafx

Below is my controller for my javafx project. My goal is to get some default values configured in DemoConfig class, which is injected as a bean in DemoController, so I have to use @PostConstuct.

And just so the value can be initialized properly, the controller has to implement the initialize method.

Here is the DemoController code:

```
@Component
public class DemoController implements Initializable
{

    public TextField platformName;

    public TextField platformVersion;

    public TextField deviceName;

    public TextField appActivity;

    public TextField appPackage;

    @Autowired
    private DemoConfig demoConfig;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)
    {
        platformName.setText(demoConfig.getPlatformName());

        platformVersion.setText(demoConfig.getPlatformVersion());

        deviceName.setText(demoConfig.getDeviceName());

        appActivity.setText(demoConfig.getAppActivity());

        appPackage.setText(demoConfig.getAppPackage());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        platformName = new TextField(demoConfig.getPlatformName());

        platformVersion = new TextField(demoConfig.getPlatformVersion());

        deviceName = new TextField(demoConfig.getDeviceName());

        appActivity = new TextField(demoConfig.getAppActivity());

        appPackage = new TextField(demoConfig.getAppPackage());
    }


}
```

Actually the init() and the initialize(URL, ResourceBundle) does the same thing, but I cannot apply @PostConstruct to initialize(URL, ResourceBundle) because the below exception :

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Lifecycle method annotation requires a no-arg method:**

I can settle for these two methods working together, but actually the init() method is just there to ensure the demoConfig bean is injected properly before initialization. I wonder if there's a more elegant way to do this coding? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming this is the controller for an FXML file, it's **always** an error to instantiate fields in the controller if they correspond to elements defined in the FXML file. You should remove the `init()` method entirely, and just have the `initialize()` method. (If you then get null pointer exceptions from the `initialize()` method, then something else is wrong in code you haven't posted, e.g. the `fx:id`s don't map correctly to the field names.) As an aside, it's not good practice to make your controls `public`; use `@FXML private TextField platformName ;` etc.

Comment: I believe the life-cycle will be: **(1)** Bean instantiated by Spring; **(2)** Spring performs dependency injection for Spring-related injection points (i.e. the `@Autowired`-annotated fields/methods); **(3)** Spring executes any `@PostConstruct`-annotated methods; **(4)** The `FXMLLoader` performs dependency injection for FXML-related fields; **(5)** The `FXMLLoader` invokes the initialize method.

Comment: In other words, you should only need the `initialize` method since your `DemoConfig` instance will have been injected by the time that method is invoked. With that in mind, and if you follow the advice of @James_D, everything should work. If you still have a problem, please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating said problem along with the full error(s).

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved! It is a controller for an FXML file, but why is instantiating fields in the controller an error? I am kinda new to javafx. @James_D

Comment: Because they are instantiated by the FXMLLoader when it parses the FXML file.

Comment: But my goad is to have these fields read some default values from a spring properties file when the stage first started, can fxmlloader do that without controller? Like say set fx:value to read from application.properties? What is your recommend approach?

Comment: Your `initialize()` method does exactly that. Leave that as it is, and delete the `init()` method, which is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `init()` method is completely redundant, and should be deleted. The correct controller class should look like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class DemoController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private TextField platformName;

    @FXML
    private TextField platformVersion;

    @FXML
    private TextField deviceName;

    @FXML
    private TextField appActivity;

    @FXML
    private TextField appPackage;

    @Autowired
    private DemoConfig demoConfig;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)
    {
        platformName.setText(demoConfig.getPlatformName());

        platformVersion.setText(demoConfig.getPlatformVersion());

        deviceName.setText(demoConfig.getDeviceName());

        appActivity.setText(demoConfig.getAppActivity());

        appPackage.setText(demoConfig.getAppPackage());
    }

}
```

The reason for this is explained by [@slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61287582/javafx-controller-initialize-method-and-spring-postconstruct-cannot-use-togeth#comment108435177_61287582) on the question. For completeness, I'll repeat that information here:

**Assuming everything is set up correctly in the code you didn't post**, when you call `load()` on your `FXMLLoader`, the following will occur:

1. The `FXMLLoader` will read the FXML file, and, seeing the `fx:controller` attribute, will get an instance of the specified class using its controller factory. Since you've presumably configured the controller factory to use the Spring Application Context to supply the controller, it will request the `DemoController` bean from the application context.
2. The Spring application context will instantiate the `DemoController`.
3. The Spring application context will inject any dependencies into the `DemoController` instance. In this case, that means it will inject the `demoConfig` field.
4. The Spring application context will call any `@PostConstruct`-annotated methods. In your original version, this means it will call the `init()` method, which instantiates the text fields and sets their text to the values from the `demoConfig`. Since these text fields are not the ones defined in the FXML file, they **are not part of the UI**, and this has no visible effect. In the correct version above, there are no `@PostConstruct`-annotated methods, and this step does nothing.
5. The `FXMLLoader` continues to parse the FXML file, instantiating the text fields defined in it. If their `fx:id` attributes match the names of either `public` fields, or (better) `@FXML`-annotated non-public fields, these fields will be initialized by the text fields defined as part of parsing the FXML file. (These are the text fields that are part of the UI.). So, in your original version, the text fields initialized in the `init()` method are immediately replaced by the text fields defined in the FXML file (so all the work done in the `init()` method is immediately lost).
6. The `initialize()` method is invoked on the controller. The definition of this method in both your version and the version I posted above now sets the text of the *correct* text fields (i.e., the ones defined in the FXML file that are part of the UI) to the values in `demoConfig`.

As you can see, everything you do in your `init()` method is redundant (because is sets the text of text fields that are never displayed in the UI), and is immediately undone anyway (because the `FXMLLoader` immediately replaces the text fields it defines with new text fields).

Consequently, you should simply delete the `init()` method as shown above. If that fails to do what you want, then there are other errors in code you haven't posted.

Note that I also changed the scope of the controller to be `prototype`. If you were to load the FXML file more than once, you would get a new set of text fields each time, and you would need a new controller instance specifically for that set of controls. When using Spring with JavaFX, all controllers should always be prototypes.